# C++ Setting Element in Struct Array = NULL

Tags: c++, arrays, function, struct, null

So what my code does right now is it creates a deck of cards using an emulated stack (since I could not figure out how to implement a real stack in c++).The cards are then shuffled, and then the deck is split in half and passed to two players, `p1` and `p2`. Then the user is allowed a peek at `p1`'s cards, which are numbered from 1 to 26, and the user can select a number from 1 to 26 to choose that card and put it into play.

I basically have to have code that goes through `p1`'s cards, sees if the card you chose is equal to a card in `p1`'s stack of cards, and if theyre equal, then I need to set that element equal to NULL.
Only problem is `p1`'s array consists of chars and ints because it is an array of structs. Otherwise, setting things to NULL would not be a problem.

After I get that specific element that you chose equal to NULL, I then have to push all of the elements after that NULL element, one space forward, so something like

```
p1[x] = p1[x+1];
```

Here is the beginning of my code where the struct is and where main is:

```
struct Card{
  char suit[10];
  int number;
};

void playGame(Card p1[], Card p2[]);
void fillDeck(Card *deck);
void fillPlayerDeck(Card deck[], Card p1[], Card p2[]);
void printDeck(Card deck[], Card p1[], Card p2[]);
void shuffleDeck(Card *deck);
void throwCard(Card p1[], Card p2[], Card p1cardsThrown[], Card p2cardsThrown[]);
//string toString(Card p1[], Card p2[], Card p1New[], Card p2New[]);

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
   Card deck[52];
   Card p1[26];
   Card p2[26];
   //Card p1New[26];
   //Card p2New[26];
   Card p1cardsThrown[26];
   Card p2cardsThrown[26];
   fillDeck(deck);
   shuffleDeck(deck);
   fillPlayerDeck(deck, p1, p2);
   printDeck(deck, p1, p2);
   throwCard(p1, p2, p1cardsThrown, p2cardsThrown);
   //playGame(p1, p2, p1cardsThrown, p2cardsThrown);  
}
```

And here is the problem code, my throwCard function:

```
void throwCard(Card p1[], Card p2[], Card p1cardsThrown[], Card p2cardsThrown[]){
   printf("\nWhich of your cards would you like to play?\n");
   int i = 0;
   for(i; i < 26; i++){
      printf("%d: %d of %s\n", i, p1[i].number, p1[i].suit);
   }
   int cardNumber;
   cin >> cardNumber;
   printf("You chose %d: the %d of %s!", cardNumber, p1[cardNumber].number, p1[cardNumber].suit);


   //HERE IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS ACTUALLY HAPPENING
   //check which card was thrown, then move that card out of array
   for(int x = 0; x<26; x++){
      if(p1[cardNumber].number = p1[x].number){
         if(p1[cardNumber].suit = p1[x].suit){
            p1[cardNumber].number = NULL;
            p1[cardNumber].suit = NULL;
            for(int y = x; y < 26; y++){
               if(p1[y].number = NULL){
                  if(p1[y].suit = NULL){
                     p1[y] = p1[y + 1];
                     printf("This is P1's new deck");
                     printf("%d: %d of %s\n", x, p1[x].number, p1[x].suit);
                  }   
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

And here are the exact errors I am receiving:

```
EgyptianRatScrew3.cpp: In function 'void throwCard(Card*, Card*, Card*, Card*)':
EgyptianRatScrew3.cpp:54:33: error: invalid array assignment
          if(p1[cardNumber].suit = p1[x].suit){
                                 ^
EgyptianRatScrew3.cpp:55:35: warning: converting to non-pointer type 'int' from NULL [-Wconversion-null]
             p1[cardNumber].number = NULL;
                                   ^
EgyptianRatScrew3.cpp:56:33: error: incompatible types in assignment of 'long long int' to 'char [10]'
             p1[cardNumber].suit = NULL;
                                 ^
EgyptianRatScrew3.cpp:58:32: warning: converting to non-pointer type 'int' from NULL [-Wconversion-null]
                if(p1[y].number = NULL){
                                ^
EgyptianRatScrew3.cpp:59:33: error: incompatible types in assignment of 'long long int' to 'char [10]'
                   if(p1[y].suit = NULL){
                                 ^
```

Comment: Well for one you are doing assignments inside an if when you should be doing a comparison

Comment: You try to assign NULL when you should just assign `0`. `NULL` is for pointers, `0` is for numeric values. If you declare a variable `int i = 0` but `int* i = NULL`.

Also, with c++ you can use `std::stack` if you need a readymade implementation of a stack. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stack/stack/

Comment: Use a standard container like a vector and once you find the card erase it from the vector.

Comment: I guess if I have p1[cardNumber].number = 0 then i can have it checked in the if statement to be true or false, so yeah that part works.

Comment: I just thought that along with
p1[cardNumber].number = 0;
I would have to do
p1[cardNumber].suit = ""; 
as well, but I can just check the number condition. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few problems here.  Lets start with your `if` statements:

```
if(p1[cardNumber].number = p1[x].number)

if(p1[cardNumber].suit = p1[x].suit)

if(p1[y].number = NULL)

if(p1[y].suit = NULL)
```

These are all assignments.  You want to use `==`, to compare values, not `=`, which assigns to them:

```
if(p1[cardNumber].number == p1[x].number)

if(p1[cardNumber].suit == p1[x].suit)

if(p1[y].number == NULL)

if(p1[y].suit == NULL)
```

`NULL` is meant to be used for pointers.  `char[10]` and `int` are both non-pointers, so assigning `NULL` to them isn't valid and doesn't make sense.  `NULL` is also just a macro for `0`, and if you have C++11, `nullptr` is what you should be using.

In my opinion, the ideal solution would be to change your `Card` struct and if checks slightly:

```
enum class Suit //declare an enum to represent suit type
{
   Invalid,
   Spades,
   Hearts,
   Clubs,
   Diamonds
}

struct Card
{
    Suit suit_value;
    int card_value;

    Card() : suit_value(Suit::Invalid), card_value(0) {}
};
```

and

```
if(p1[y].number == 0)// have -1 or 0 be an invalid number

if(p1[y].suit = Suit::Invalid)// check for invalid suit
```

I didn't take a close look at your code, and it may not even make sense to have invalid options.  An `enum` for `Suit` is definitely the way to go though.

Answer (score 0):

At this part:

```
if(p1[y].suit = NULL)
```

You should compare, instead of assigning:

```
if(p1[y].suit == NULL)
```

Now, about the assignments, from the C++98 docs:

> A null-pointer constant is an integral constant expression that
>   evaluates to zero (such as 0 or 0L).

It is a pointer by default (`void*`), but you can cast into int if you want. Like:

```
p1[cardNumber].number = (int) NULL;
```

Which is the same as assigning to 0:

```
p1[cardNumber].number = 0;
```

Now this one, doesn't make sense at all:

```
p1[cardNumber].suit = NULL;
```

You are assigning NULL to a vector of chars (`char suit[10]`). You can either assign each one of the vector positions to 0 (or NULL with casting as I discussed before), or use a pointer, and alloc as necessary. If you use:

```
struct Card{
  char *suit;
  int number;
};
```

This becomes valid:

```
p1[cardNumber].suit = NULL;
```

And as a bonus you save some memory! You can just assign the string pointer of the suit to the card, and voila, everything works.

Comment: Almost right but you have a few misconceptions and terminology problems. For one, "vector" in C++ is well-defined to mean something else.

Comment: Indeed, don't mistake `std::vector` with a well-defined, language-independant vector.

Comment: But don't mistake it with `std::array`!